# Why does an AJAX call sometimes redirect the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page that contains 3 iframes, the top header, left navigation and the content iframe.

(this is a legacy application).

The page that contains the 3 iframes makes an jQuery AJAX call to a page:

`/users/getNotifications.aspx`

Sometimes (I believe when I am not logged in) the browser redirects to the URL of my AJAX call i.e. localhost/users/getNotifications.aspx

I obviously don't want it to redirect like this, any idea why this may be happening?

Note:

My page responds with:

```
 Response.ContentType = "text/html";
 Response.Write(resultInHtml);
```

Also, the page doesn't redirect if the user isn't logged in.

This is the method I call to get the data using an ajax requesT:

```
var x = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: webRoot + "users/getNotifications.aspx",
            cache: false,
            success: function (payload) {
                if (payload.length > 0) {
                    $("#users-popup").html(payload);
                }
                displayPopup();                
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you authorize to redirect that page with login or something else that way it will not simply move, check IsAuthenticated then redirect your page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your javascript doesn't deal well with whatever result comes back from your page when you are not logged in. Possibly it is trying to extract a value that doesn't exist in this context and thus throws an error.

This will then mean it doesn't finish running the function so any "return false" or other method of preventing default behaviour is not running and so the default click behaviour is occuring and navigating to a new page.

Without more code though that is just a theory.

Comment: the ajax request is called when the page loads, it isn't based on any event (other than page ready event).

Comment: Perhaps then you should show us more code as the other Chris suggested in comments so we can see what code is going wrong and perhaps help you to work out why. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints has some good hints on asking a good question.